# How do I change the path for the files that my Espressif-IDF project is using in Eclipse:?

Tags: eclipse, ide, embedded, esp32

I'm creating a sample ESP-IDF project but upon creating a Espressif-IDF project in Eclipse, I see the following files are already imported, but they're referencing to a different project's path and not the current one. In other words, they're located inside a local directory cloned from one of the ESP-IDF repo's which apparently isn't the latest version.

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"
```

How does one go about changing the path such that when I compile, it takes the files from the specified path and not where it's taking from. Does it have to do with `IDF_PATH` and `IDF_TOOLS_PATH`? (can't set them in Eclipse as I don't see C/C++ build section for some reason)

Following is the path the project is using that I need to change...

```
-- Adding linker script /Users/eclipse-workspace/Project/build/esp-idf/esp32/esp32_out.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.0.2/UdpSender/esp32/esp-idf/components/esp32/ld/esp32.project.ld.in
-- Adding linker script /Users/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.0.2/UdpSender/esp32/esp-idf/components/esp32/ld/esp32.peripherals.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.0.2/UdpSender/esp32/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.0.2/UdpSender/esp32/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.libgcc.ld
```

Comment: you can set the path to IDF as environment variable IDF_PATH

Comment: right so just to clarify, IDF_PATH determines what path the ESP-IDF project is going to take?

Comment: it is the path to the IDF framework location. https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/index.html#get-started-get-esp-idf

Comment: despite changing the IDF path/tools, I see it still takes the python files from the older directory